# T-SQL: create results in a comma seperated combined single row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT        
         EQUITY_DIVISION_25_NAME Broker, 
         COUNT(tbl_user_details.USER_ID) new, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(tbl_user_details.USER_ID) DESC) Rank
     FROM            
         TBL_FEES_MASTER RIGHT 
     OUTER JOIN
         TBL_USER_CREATE ON TBL_FEES_MASTER.FEE_ID = TBL_USER_CREATE.FEE_ID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TBL_USER_DETAILS ON TBL_USER_CREATE.USER_ID = TBL_USER_DETAILS.USER_ID
     WHERE 
         Joined_dt >= (SELECT MAX(last_report_run)
                       FROM new_lance_table
                       WHERE last_report_run < (SELECT MAX(last_report_run) 
                                                FROM new_lance_table)) 
                         AND (joined_dt <= GETDATE()) 
     GROUP BY 
         EQUITY_DIVISION_25_NAME) a
```

I get table results:

```
Broker              new Rank
-----------------------------
Todd Schuster       7   1
Tony Ketterling     7   1
Al Palmonari        4   2
Randall Wall        4   2
Edmund Sperry       3   3
Eric Lee    3       3
Steve Stringham     3   3
Timothy Gulla       2   4
Troy Peterson       2   4
Tuiono Malakai      2   4
Nancy Umbreit       2   4
Steve Goodsell      2   4
Sandy Dunkley       1   5
Gary Rosine         1   5
Ian Chait           1   5
Nancy Pearce-Harris 1   5
William Hochstedler 1   5
Troy C Peterson     1   5
```

How can I query to make it so the results show up like this:

- Rank 1: Tie! Todd Schuster (7), Tony Ketterling (7)
- Rank 2: Tie! Al Palmonari (4), Randall Wall (4)
- Rank 3: Tie! Edmund Sperry (3), Eric Lee (3), Steve Stringham (3)

Comment: Thank you Zohar Peled, I have no idea how to make it pretty like that.

Comment: About *making things pretty*. Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/311071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE(
   Broker VARCHAR(29)
  ,new    VARCHAR(13)
  ,Rank   VARCHAR(8)
);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Todd Schuster',7,1);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Tony Ketterling',7,1);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Al Palmonari',4,2);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Randall Wall',4,2);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Edmund Sperry',3,3);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Eric Lee',3,NULL);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Steve Stringham',3,3);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Timothy Gulla',2,4);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Troy Peterson',2,4);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Tuiono Malakai',2,4);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Nancy Umbreit',2,4);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Steve Goodsell',2,4);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Sandy Dunkley',1,5);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Gary Rosine',1,5);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Ian Chait',1,5);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Nancy Pearce-Harris',1,5);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('William Hochstedler',1,5);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl(Broker,new,Rank) VALUES ('Troy C Peterson',1,5);
```

--I use the declared table variable and a simple `SELECT * FROM @dummyTbl` to *mock-up* you query

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    /*Place your own query here*/
    SELECT * FROM @dummyTbl
)
SELECT 'Rank ' + CAST(t.Rank AS VARCHAR(10)) + ': Tie! '
      +STUFF(
      (
        SELECT ', ' + x.Broker + ' (' + CAST(x.new AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
        FROM CTE AS x
        WHERE x.Rank=t.Rank
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,2,'') 
FROM CTE AS t
GROUP BY t.Rank
```

The result

```
NULL
Rank 1: Tie! Todd Schuster (7), Tony Ketterling (7)
Rank 2: Tie! Al Palmonari (4), Randall Wall (4)
Rank 3: Tie! Edmund Sperry (3), Steve Stringham (3)
Rank 4: Tie! Timothy Gulla (2), Troy Peterson (2), Tuiono Malakai (2), Nancy Umbreit (2), Steve Goodsell (2)
Rank 5: Tie! Sandy Dunkley (1), Gary Rosine (1), Ian Chait (1), Nancy Pearce-Harris (1), William Hochstedler (1), Troy C Peterson (1)
```

### Short explanation:

A simple `SELECT Rank FROM CTE GROUP BY Rank` will return with a distinct list of Ranks. This numbers are extended by some constant characters. But you would not be allowed to access other columns than `Rank`, unless you'd add them to your `GROUP BY`...

But: You can use a *sub-select*, in which `t.Rank` is the only column in use. The other columns are taken from a second call to the same table, but aliased as `x`.

The rest (`STUFF()` in combination with `FOR XML` to concat values) is rather easy. There are tons of questions and answers around this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your current result into a temp table, and then loop from 1 to max(rank) and do string combination.

Comment: Uhh, this sound so... so... procedural... If ever possible one should avoid loops in SQL queries...